# Retrieve truncated file on NTFS

Tags: files, data-recovery, ntfs

I was trying to replace 512 head bytes of a disk image using `dd` command, but I missed to use `conv=notrunc`. Now image size changed to 512. The hosting disk had not any write afterward.

Is it possible to retrieve a `dd` truncated file? What about disk images?

Comment: The bits may be somewhere on the filesystem though will require data recovery tools (or $$$ services) to restore, assuming the bits haven't be reused. (How do you do backups?)

Comment: Since the start of file is known (the file is already there) and size is also known, (I know previous size, and it can be extracted from partition table of image), there must be a method to wrap around start and end point?!

Comment: I'm not really loosing the data, but I'm curious to know if there is a method to deal such situations, preferably using linux tools.

Comment: Filesystems are rather more complicated than having a "start and end point" somewhere. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43834/file-is-mysteriously-empty-options-to-recover?rq=1 for starters?

Comment: What type of filesystem is it?    ext, xfs, or what?

Comment: Filesystem on the host disk is NTFS.